# How to install Cmake on Django Azure webapp?

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a Django Webapp on Azure.
One of the libraries I need, depends on Cmake, so im getting the error :

```
CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _dlib_pybind11
```

Now, in order to install Cmake on the service, I need to make some SH file, or manually insert some "startup" commands, is there a way to "pre-install" Cmake before the install of requirements.txt?

UPDATE (This one works + deployed on azure for confirmation):

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8-alpine-2020-12-19

RUN apk update
RUN apk add lapack-dev

RUN apk add gfortran musl-dev g++ freetype-dev
RUN apk add gcc clang cmake python-dev
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
RUN apk add make automake g++ subversion python3-dev

LABEL Name=ydemo Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 8000

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000

ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN chmod g+w /app
RUN chmod g+w /app/db.sqlite3
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache libmemcached-dev zlib-dev 
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers \
    && pip3 install pip --upgrade 
RUN python3 -m pip install Pillow
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools wheel
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install cmake
RUN python3 -m pip install dlib
RUN python3 -m pip install numpy

RUN python3 -m pip install opencv-python
COPY . /app
```

Comment: What deploy method did you use?

Comment: I've used the standard of deployment as a code, but now after tons of research got to the idea that I should just dockerize it.

Comment: Hi @SlavaBugz, do you mind sharing your solution as the answer?

Comment: Will post it in a few hours, currently it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8-alpine-2020-12-19


RUN apk update
RUN apk add lapack-dev

RUN apk add gfortran musl-dev g++ freetype-dev
RUN apk add gcc clang cmake python-dev
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
RUN apk add make automake g++ subversion python3-dev

LABEL Name=ydemo Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 8000

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000

ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN chmod g+w /app
RUN chmod g+w /app/db.sqlite3
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache libmemcached-dev zlib-dev 
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers \
    && pip3 install pip --upgrade 
RUN python3 -m pip install Pillow
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools wheel
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install cmake
RUN python3 -m pip install dlib
RUN python3 -m pip install numpy

RUN python3 -m pip install opencv-python
COPY . /app
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to run the cmd `pip install cmake` , and then run `pip install dlib`. if you are using conda follow below command `sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake`. CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: `_dlib_pybind11` Which is telling you that CMake isn't installed, or, You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.

We could refer to this [doc](https://xspdf.com/resolution/30042174.html) and [ticket](https://github.com/Greenwolf/social_mapper/issues/25) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats not what i was asking.

Comment: When you deploy an app as webapp on azure, you don't really have a cmd to install cmake essentialls, so the pip installs will not work, because it needs installation of sudo first, so now im. actually trying to dockerize it to solve it.

Comment: Hi @SlavaBugz, We could run pip install cmake in the Azure DevOps pipeline, If have any misunderstanding, could you re-describe more details about scenario?

Comment: Sure! When deploy a Django app on Azure as code (the other option is via docker), Azure will handle everything for you, problem is, it will start with installing requirements.txt, but to install cmake library and dlib library, you first need to run the command you wrote in your answer, so your answer is correct, but i did not find a way to actually run this command before Azure starts installing the requirements.txt

Comment: Could you try to run pip install cmake and re-run pip install -r requirements.txt to install the requirements.txt

Comment: I can install cmake via requirements, but, it's still not all that is needed to install dlib on Linux, you will still need to run the sudo command you mentioned, if not, then you will get the error that's in my question. you can recreate the error by trying to install cmake and dlib via pip on a clean linux.